# setting font color of <a> inside a li tag

Tags: css

My markup looks like:

```
<div class="c1">
      <li class="c2"><a href="">blah</a></li>
</div>
```

I want the text blah to be red.

c1 is used other places, so I want to drill down as much as possible without affecting other markup.

Comment: Your <li> is straight inside your div? How does that work out for you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this style definition in your css-file:

```
div.c1 li.c2 a {
  color: red;
}
```

PS: Having your `<li>` tag inside your `<div>`-tag without an `<ul>`-tag is not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

```
<style>
  div.c1 li.c2 a { color: red; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="c1">
      <li class="c2"><a href="">blah</a></li>
</div>
<style>
  div.c1 li.c2 a { color: red; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

The most specific CSS selectors would probably be

```
div.c1 > li.c2 > a:link,
div.c1 > li.c2 > a:active,
div.c1 > li.c2 > a:hover,
div.c1 > li.c2 > a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

The more specific the CSS selectors, the less work for the browser's rendering engine.

However, something is wrong with your markup if this is supposed to be HTML and the <li> element's parent is a <div> instead of <ol> or <ul>.

Comment: CSS selectors are evaluated from right to left, so the "less work for the browser" part is wrong.

Comment: With &gt; between the elements in the CSS selector (i.e. immediate parent-child relationship of the elements), the browser only needs to check up to three levels of nested elements, maximum for each &lt;a&gt; element.

If you just specify "any ancestor" (i.e. just a space between the elements in the CSS selector), the browser needs to check all ancestors back to the root &lt;html&gt; for ever &lt;a&gt; element.

Checking three levels max is less work than checking all levels.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following rule:

```
div.c1 li.c2 a {
    color: red;
}
```

This matches `a` tags inside of `li` tags with class `c2` inside of `div` tags with class `c1`.

For added uniqueness, you might want to give the `a` tag its own class name.

Also, `li` tags should only appear inside of list tags. (`ul` or `ol`).
Did  you mean `<li class="c1">`?

Answer (score 0):

```
.c1 .c2 a {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.c2 a
{
     color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do (very specific).

```
.c1 .c2 a { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First choose the div you want to change which is .c2 inside this is a link which should be selected like

```
.c2 a { color:red }
```