# How to use jQuery in ASP.NET to change color of 'li'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to change the color of all the `<li>` links on web app using jQuery, but don't know why it is not working?

I have my style statement at the top in my **layout.cshtml** page, and the jQuery function at the bottom.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Contoso University</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <style>
         li {color: blue;}
        .emphasis {color: indianred;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Contoso University", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li> 

                    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        if (!User.IsInRole("Instructor"))
                        {
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Students", "Index", "Student")</li>
                        }
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Courses", "Index", "Course")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Instructors", "Index", "Instructor")</li>
                        if (!User.IsInRole("Student") && !User.IsInRole("Instructor"))
                        {
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Departments", "Index", "Department")</li>
                        }
                        if (!User.IsInRole("Student"))
                        {
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Enrollments", "Index", "Enrollment")</li>
                        }
                    }

                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Contoso University</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @*<script>
        $('li').addClass('emphasis');        
    </script>*@

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('li').addClass('emphasis');
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your li markup?

Comment: did u add jquery library to ur page

Comment: Yes, it is on the latest version.

Comment: the problem is that during bootstrapping of the page jquery can't process those tags

Comment: Remove any code that is actually commented out from your example. I'm pretty sure `@* *@` comments code out in razor syntax. Also, look at your console (F12 on most browsers) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425158/jquery-on-method-with-load-event and check on JQuery .on which can always help you bootstrap and no need to be on every page for  some event

Comment: No errors in the console. Removed all the commented out codes and still nothing. Don't know what is wrong?

Comment: You are coloring links within a ``li``.  Your css should be ``li a { }`` not just ``li { }``, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585855/setting-font-color-of-a-inside-a-li-tag

Comment: @Rick, I did `$('li a').addClass('emphasis');` as @Rion had suggested. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Truecolor The question is just Html and jQuery. Could you post your code at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Truecolor, you don't need jquery to do any of that, remove it and change it in the ``<style>`` on the page.  ``li a`` is exactly how you would style it.

Comment: So, I removed the jQuery function call and tried the `<style>` statement with and without `a` in `li` and no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a lot of trials & errors, found out I was using the wrong selector. Posting the answer just in case if someone else has this issue.

```
 <script>
        $('.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a').css('color', 'red');
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options...

**JavaScript**

If you're trying to color the bullet, working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nk2uf2L/)

```
$('li').addClass('emphasis');
```

If you're trying to color the hyperlink, working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89thkav2/)

```
$('li a').addClass('emphasis');
```

If you're trying to color both the bullet and the hyperlink, working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgd0s1k1/)

```
$('li a, li').addClass('emphasis');
```

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">TEST 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">TEST 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">TEST 3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">TEST 4</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">TEST 5</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
li {color: blue;}
.emphasis {color: indianred;}
```

Comment: But my links aren't  `<a href=` links. They are helper functions `@Html.ActionLink`. Is it the same? Thanks for the help, I am going to look into it more to make this work.

Comment: @Truecolor - look at the html your generating - `ActionLink()` generates an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you wrap your `<script>` code within a document-ready block so that it executes when your page (and dependencies) have been loaded :

```
<script>
    // This will not execute until jQuery (and your page) have been loaded
    $(function(){
        $('li a').addClass('emphasis');       
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I had tried it that way also, but still the same. Do I have to do it in each page's Index views instead of the layout page?

Comment: I just noticed that you have actual links within your `<li>` elements, which will slightly change how you need to target those to color them. You'll need to either use the `$('li a')` selector to target the links, or adjust your CSS to explicitly target any `<a>` elements below the emphasis element using `.emphasis a { color: indianred; }`. Additionally, try checking your Developer Tools (F12) to ensure that your actual jQuery code is being loaded as expected and that there aren't any errors within the Console.

Comment: Nothing worked. I was only able to change the color of the University, using the `.navbar-brand` class.

Answer (score -2):

try to make a static html

without change the jquery code to see if its works .

```
  <li>test</li>
```

if it works , that means your Jquery code fired before your html li is generated.

Comment: obviously the case

Comment: should be a comment anyway

Comment: Yes, the "test" showed up in color. So, what am I doing incorrectly? I thought I am supposed to have the jQuery statement at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I don't have enough points to comment rather than my own post . Warp you JQuery function in $(document).ready(function () { }. JQuery statement at the bottom doesn't necessary mean  it will be execute last . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page